# SQL - Join or Union two tables checking for duplicates?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say I have two tables as follows.

**ALL_SPORTS**

```
ID  Name  Age  Sport        Result  Date    Weather
----------------------------------------------------
1   Jake   12  Basketball   Won     1/2/13  Sunny
2   Jill   13  Tennis       Lost    2/3/13  Sunny
3   Sam    14  Basketball   Won     4/5/14  Cloudy
4   Ann    15  Football     Won     6/7/18  Cloudy
5   Will   18  Track        Lost    11/12/13 Rainy
```

&

**Sports_results**

```
ID   Sport   Result  Date
----------------------------
1    Bball   W       1/2/13
2    Tn      L       2/3/13
2    Fball   L       1/2/14
3    Fball   L       4/9/14
3    Fball   W       4/9/14
4    Bball   L       8/9/18
5    Tk      L       11/12/13
8    pngpng  W       9/4/15
```

`ALL_SPORTS` has a lot more columns. `Sport_Results` is more specialized. They both use different ways to show Sport name (`Sports_results` uses shortened name) and result (Won and lost vs W and L).

There is some overlap between the tables but each might contain something not contained in the other table and vice versa.

I need to make a third table called ALL_RESULTS which gets all the results from ALL_RESULTS and Sports_Results checking for duplicate results. It should get the following values from the tables.

**ALL_RESULTS** (desired results)

```
ID  Name  Age  Sport        Result  Date    Weather
---------------------------------------------------
(From ALL_SPORTS)
1   Jake   12  Basketball   Won     1/2/13  Sunny
2   Jill   13  Tennis       Lost    2/3/13  Sunny
3   Sam    14  Basketball   Won     4/5/14  Cloudy
4   Ann    15  Football     Won     6/7/18  Cloudy
5   Will   18  Track        Lost    11/12/13 Rainy

(From Sports_results)
ID   Sport   Result  Date
-----------------------------
3    Fball   L       4/9/14
3    Fball   W       4/9/14
4    Bball   L       8/9/18
8    pngpng  W       9/4/15
```

Currently I'm doing a Union but since the formats of values contained in both tables is different and `ALL_SPORTS` contains more columns, Union cannot find duplicates.

Would love some tips! TIA

Comment: Why not adding some additional identity column ? What about having multiple sport_results for same day ?

Answer (score 1):

Just select the common columns and convert to the same format:

```
select a.ID, a.Sport, a.Result, a.Date
from all_sports a
union   -- on purpose to remove duplicates
select sr.ID, sr.Sport,
       (case sr.Result when 'W' then 'Won' when 'L' then 'Lost' end), 
       sr.Date
from Sports_results sr;
```

Comment: But ALL_RESULTS will have more columns and there will be a lot of null values coming from Sports_Results. So a row for the same event in both originating tables will have more columns in ALL_RESULTS than Sports_results.

Comment: It will be more like ```select a.ID, a.Sport, a.name, a.age, a.Result, a.Date, a.Weahter
from all_sports a
union   -- on purpose to remove duplicates
select sr.ID, sr.Sport,
       (case sr.Result when 'W' then 'Won' when 'L' then 'Lost' end), 
       sr.Date
from Sports_results sr;```

Comment: @redtopi . . . I think this answers the question that you asked.